# password redacting logger

Tags: java, log4j, logback

Does anyone know of a log4j or logback class that can redact passwords based on a regular expression?

It looks trivial to write one, but just wanted to check if there was one already out there?

Thanks.

---

Update:

From the comments, it doesn't sound like such a sensible idea ;-)

@Mike:

Good point for new development.

Although for legacy apps, we might not want to modify the code.

And for 3rd party libraries, we might not be able to modify the code.

@Thorbjorn:

A regular expression might be `"<password>(.*?)</password>"` for example.

Comment: What's the application for this? My initial thought is that if you need something like this, then you've done something wrong.

Comment: What would a regular expression identifying passwords be?

Comment: Not sure its possible unless the thing logging the password uses a specific format. I assume this is occuring because something is logging http requests, including posted params?

Comment: If you have un-redacted logs that you want to send to a third party, you can use Sublime Text to retrospectively redact them - see  https://codingrob.medium.com/how-to-redact-text-from-hundreds-of-text-files-in-less-than-60-seconds-511b4b91c2d8

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Logback offers regexp replacement in layout specs.

See the example at:
http://logback.qos.ch/manual/layouts.html#cwOptions

Something like:

```
<pattern>%-5level - %replace(%msg){'&lt;password>(.*)&lt;/password>', 'XXXX'}%n</pattern>
```